# How to change the Font styles and face in Android?

Tags: android, fonts

I want to change the font face and styles in android. How to do this? Am using emulator. Is this possible to change in emulator. Is there any permissions available to do that. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

in android only five fonttype-face

TypeFace

```
Typeface.DEFAULT
Typeface.MONOSPACE
Typeface.SANS_SERIF
Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD
Typeface.SERIF
```

and font-type

```
Typeface.NORMAL
Typeface.BOLD
Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC
Typeface.ITALIC
```

you can use like as

```
textView.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT, Typeface.BOLD);
```

and other way is you can `download any .ttf file` and put it in asset folder and use like as this

```
Typeface type=Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),
        "DroidSansMono.ttf");
textView.setTypeface(type, null);
```

Comment: Now one more type is added DEFAULT_BOLD in android. So now there is a 5 type of typeface is available.

Answer (score 4):

You can change the font style and font face in your XML files. For example if you want to change your Button's style and face.  Choose your button in xml and follow the below methods :

```
Button -> Right Click -> Properties -> Typeface and style
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to change in code ;

This is good reference;

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/customize-android-fonts/

Answer (score 2):

what you want?. Do you want to change the font face and styles of  text in textview. if yes then use this

```
Typeface type = Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getAssets(),"your font name");
text.setTypeface(type);
```

and for styles use these links:

1. [Style-resource](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/style-resource.html)
2. [Themes](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a font which is not default (like "Helvetica") for the text in Android application then put the font file(Helvetic.ttf) in assets folder and do use this code as below:

```
Typeface tf= Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "Helvetica.ttf");
  TextView mTextView =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
    mTextView.setTypeface(tf);
```

Answer (score 1):

if u want to use custom font jus download .ttf file and put the file into assets folder
and use like this:

```
TextView tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
Typeface  tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(), "fonts/arial.ttf");
tv.setTypeface(tf);
```