# Android Listview font style

Tags: android, android-listview, custom-font

I am new in android. In android listview i want to change the font in my own style. Please reply. thanks in advance step by step how to change the font in list view.

in xml....

Comment: Santosh this is a repeat question

Comment: Have a look at this for your answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973270/using-a-custom-typeface-in-android

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2888508/how-to-change-the-font-on-the-textview

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7513088/how-to-change-the-font-styles-and-face-in-android

Comment: All the links that I paste above are exact duplicates of your question. There is no way you could do it from XML.

Answer (score 0):

```
Typeface typeBold = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/helveticabold.ttf");
Typeface typeNormal = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/helvetica.ttf");
```

More information try the following links

[example1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4576441/custom-font-in-android-listview)

[example2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9531647/android-own-font-in-listview)

Answer (score 0):

```
In android listview i want to change the font in my own style.
```

By this, I suppose you want to change the font in the child view that is being displayed in the list. For that you need to set the `typeface` of the `TextView` inside the `getView()` as follows

First initialize the font in the constructor of the adapter maybe as follows

```
private Typeface typeFace;
public MyContructor(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        typeFace=Typeface.createFromAsset(mContext.getAssets(), "Fonts/GrinchedRegular.ttf"));
    }
```

and then in the `getView()`

```
@Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent)
    {
        if (convertView == null)
        {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.sample, null);
        }
        myText = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.my_text);
        myText.setTypeface(typeFace);
        return convertView;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First add your font file in your assets folder and use this code

```
Typeface arial = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/arial.ttf");
name_txt.setTypeface(arial);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Customized List -

To change to a different built-in font, use android:typeface in List Item XML

or setTypeface() in getView of ArrayAdopter.

```
public class CustomeArrayAdopter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
int res;
Typeface tf;

public CustomeArrayAdopter(Context ctx, int resource,  
    List<String> items) {

super(ctx, res,items);
res=resource;
tf=Typeface.createFromAsset(ctx.getAssets(),"font/Arial.ttf");
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
//Apply new TypeFace here
TextView item_text=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.listItemtv);
item_text.setTypeface(tf);

.....
}
```

_ }