# How we can provide the font style to text in ListView

Tags: android, eclipse, android-listview

I want to customize my  ListView.I change the color of the text in list_view but i unable to change the font style of the  ListView text.i provide the font family to the text but it does not show any changes related to the font.

this is what i have done so far...

**XML**

```
 <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40sp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textColor="@color/aqua"
        android:fontFamily="@raw/chocd"
        android:textSize="25sp"
         />
```

**Code**

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,                                         R.layout.listview_layout,R.id.txt,list1);
listview.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: How you change font ? Show your code

Comment: @user try my answer it will help u somehow

Answer (score 4):

You can use this to change to a different built-in font, use **android:typeface** in layout XML or **setTypeface()** in Java

```
Typeface type = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),""); 
   txtyour.setTypeface(type);
```

Comment: To add more for @Gaurav answer: if you need a customized font, you'll have to create a [ttf file](https://www.google.ro/#q=photoshop+ttf+fonts) (Photoshop is most popular tool to work with) and use that.

Answer (score 4):

Android doesn't allow you to set custom fonts from the XML layout.

```
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(<your TextView ID>);
Typeface typeFace = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "<file name>");
tv.setTypeface(typeFace);
```

Note that you can only run this code after `setContentView()` has been called. [For more information](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7513191/1405983).

Answer (score 2):

Say you want to get the Roboto-Light font on your TextView, put the respective font's ".ttf" file in your assets and do this to set the TextView to that format:

```
Typeface robotolight = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"Roboto-Light.ttf");
textView.setTypeface(robotolight);
```

That should work!

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own textview and use it anywhere you want. If you may use the same font in somewhere else you should definitely use this like that.

```
public class TextViewLight extends TextView {

    public TextViewLight(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init();
    }

    public TextViewLight(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public TextViewLight(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(),"fonts/opensans_light.ttf");
        setTypeface(tf);
    }

}
```

Than you can use this textview in xml like that.

```
<com.predict.android.views.TextViewLight
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/settings"/>
```

And also you should store your fonts in assets folder. So create a folder "fonts" in asset and keep them there.

If you use a custom class for light, bold, italic fonts like that, when you need to change the font of the whole application you just need to change one line in your custom textview class. It is really practical for seeing your application with different font style in seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Use custom list adapter it will give you the full freedom to change the font  style and conditional font style as well.

```
private class CustomListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter{
        private Context mContext;
        private int id;
        private List <String>items ;

        public CustomListAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId , List<String> list ) 
        {
            super(context, textViewResourceId, list);           
            mContext = context;
            id = textViewResourceId;
            items = list ;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View v, ViewGroup parent)
        {
            View mView = v ;
            if(mView == null){
                LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                mView = vi.inflate(id, null);
            }

            TextView text = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.textView);

            if(items.get(position) != null )
            {
               Typeface typeFace = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "<file name>");
tv.setTypeface(typeFace);

            }

            return mView;
        }

    }
```

and access the adapter like

```
CustomListAdapter listAdapter = new CustomListAdapter(YourActivity.this , R.layout.custom_list , mList);
listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
```