# setting TextView typeface to bold and serif separately resets each other

Tags: android

I have a textview and two spinners in my app. one spinner chooses Typeface (Default/Serif/Monospace). the other spinner chooses font style (Normal/Bold/Italic/Bold Italic).

This is my code:

```
tvQuoteTextSample = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.preview_QuoteText);
```

Setting Typeface from typeface spinner:

```
switch(selectedTypeFace)
                    {
                        case "Serif":
                            tvQuoteTextSample.setTypeface(Typeface.SERIF);
                            break;
                        case "Monospace":
                            tvQuoteTextSample.setTypeface(Typeface.MONOSPACE);
                            break;
                        default:
                            tvQuoteTextSample.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT);
                            break;
                    }
```

Setting fontStyle from fontstyle spinner:

```
switch (fontStyle) {
                        case "Bold":
                            tvQuoteTextSample.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
                            break;
                        case "Italic":
                            tvQuoteTextSample.setTypeface(null, Typeface.ITALIC);
                            break;
                        case "Bold Italic":
                            tvQuoteTextSample.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC);
                            break;
                        default:
                            tvQuoteTextSample.setTypeface(null, Typeface.NORMAL);
                            break;
                    }
```

When I apply the fontStyle spinner, the applied TypeFace resets to Default. Similarly when I apply a TypeFace, the fontStyle resets to Normal.

I want both spinners work together. i.e. Output from one spinner will apply on the textView without resetting the previous style. how to achieve this?

Comment: It seems quite **obvious** that two subsequent `setTypeFace()` instructions *override each other*. Doesn't it?

Comment: Yes :-) i understood why it is happening. but what i need to know is how to make it work :(

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change the Font styles and face in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7513088/how-to-change-the-font-styles-and-face-in-android)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you reset the `TypeFace` by providing a `null` argument when changing the style.

Instead, keep the current `TypeFace` and only change the style:

```
tvQuoteTextSample.setTypeface(tvQuoteTextSample.getTypeFace(), Typeface.BOLD);
```

Comment: it works but when I set the font style first and then set the typeface, the font style resets again. and I can not use : tvQuoteTextSample.setTypeface(tvQuoteTextSample.getTypeFace(), Typeface.SERIF);

Comment: Nevermind, I fixed it. I used a int variable FONT_STYLE to Store Typeface.BOLD in it, then used the variable to : tvQuoteTextSample.setTypeface(Typeface.SERIF, FONT_STYLE);